# AJAX framework or native jquery? drupal 7

Tags: jquery, ajax, drupal, frameworks

So, I am a little confused about this topic. Drupal 7 provides a AJAX framework which in a nutshell is how to make AJAX requests without writing javascript. For example lets say i have a link somewhere in a block which loads the most recent articles. It's not a real problem but you get the idea. I normally would write the appropriate js file using jquery's AJAX methods and so on.

The question is why i should prefer the framework instead of native jquery and vise versa ... ? There aren't many tutorials about AJAX in drupal 7 out there...

What's your opinion?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first thing is, using Drupal framework complies with drupal coding standards. using drupal framework allows this information to be hooked into by other modules and your theme to help prepare it properly, and you may edit it at a later time instead of putting another js file to edit it. It will also help with security since drupal has its security mechanisms in place. Hope this helps. Joshua

Answer (score 0):

Well jquery itself is a framework, that gives you the possibility to make AJAX calls.

AJAX is realized with a XMLHttpRequest, that provides your browser. You can interact with this object with javascript.

So your statement "native jquery" is not correct, "native javascript" would be correct.

jQuery is a framework with AJAX functionality, Drupal has it own framework for AJAX.

You see: javascript is the "native" way to access AJAX.

You can use your preferred framework (jquery, drupal, yui, ...) to "simplify" the "native" javascript way to access the ajax functionality